# Allow fetch api to fetch JSON response regardless of CORS policy

Tags: javascript, cors

```
Access to fetch has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header 
is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the 
request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

There are lots of questions online about CORS policy being blocked, but I surprisingly have not seen any answers for my question.

I am creating an NFT app that requires fetching resources from many different locations. As such, I have no access to the servers sending the json response for the token uri's, so I have no control over their CORS policy. How can I solve CORS policy error with no access to backend? I just want to get the data, and have no issue when simply requesting for the resource directly through the browser, or postman but obviously fetch api does not like it.

Comment: You can make the call for data to your own server and have that make the request to remote source and forward to response to your app.

Comment: @SQLHacks "no access to backend" might be a problem.